# How to get Duration of audio and video files in Qt without using QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, duration, qtimer

I have been working on an application where I can traverse the system drives using **QDirIterator** and look for audio/video files, grab the details using **QStandardItemModel** and display it on QTreeview. I have been successful in displaying file name, type, size, date-modified but **DURATION** is something which I am not able to do.

Here is the code:

```
// Displays Files in Detail View on Clicking Drive
void DetailView::on_DriveView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
int m_count_row = 0;

QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(0,0);
QString sPath = pSystemModel->fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath();
pSystemTreeViewModel->setRootPath(sPath);
ui->DriveListView->setRootIndex(pSystemTreeViewModel->index(sPath));

pSystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
pSystemModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs );
pSystemTreeViewModel->setFilter( QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );

QStringList m_list;
QDirIterator dirIt(sPath,QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

while (dirIt.hasNext())
{
    dirIt.next();
    if (QFileInfo(dirIt.filePath()).isFile())
    {
        if (QFileInfo(dirIt.filePath()).suffix() == "mp3" ||(QFileInfo(dirIt.filePath()).suffix() == "mts" ) ||(QFileInfo(dirIt.filePath()).suffix() == "m2ts" ))
        {
            m_list << dirIt.filePath();

            QModelIndex m_index = model->index(m_count_row, 0, QModelIndex());
            model->setHeaderData( 0, Qt::Horizontal, "Name" );
            model->setHeaderData( 1, Qt::Horizontal, "Type" );
            model->setHeaderData( 2, Qt::Horizontal, "Size" );
            model->setHeaderData( 3, Qt::Horizontal, "Date Modified" );

            model->setData( m_index, dirIt.fileName(), Qt::DecorationRole );
            QStandardItem *itemName = new QStandardItem(dirIt.fileName());
            model->setItem(m_count_row, 0, itemName);

            model->setData( m_index, dirIt.fileInfo().suffix(), Qt::DecorationRole );
            QStandardItem *itemExtention = new QStandardItem( dirIt.fileInfo().suffix());
            model->setItem(m_count_row, 1, itemExtention);

            model->setData( m_index, dirIt.fileInfo().size(), Qt::DecorationRole );
            float fFileSize = dirIt.fileInfo().size();
            float fFileKB = fFileSize / 1024; //kilobyte
            float fFileMB = fFileKB / 1024; //megabyte
            float fFinalSize = ceilf(fFileMB * 100) / 100;

            QString sSizeValue = QString::number(fFinalSize);
            QStandardItem *itemSize = new QStandardItem(sSizeValue + " MB");
            model->setItem(m_count_row, 2, itemSize);

            model->setData( m_index, dirIt.fileInfo().lastModified(), Qt::DecorationRole );
            QDateTime m_time = dirIt.fileInfo().lastModified();
            QString sTime = m_time.toString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            QStandardItem *itemDate = new QStandardItem(sTime);
            model->setItem(m_count_row, 3, itemDate);

            ui->DriveListView->setModel(model);
            ui->DriveListView->setRootIsDecorated(false);
            m_count_row++;
        }
    }

    pSystemTreeViewModel->setNameFilterDisables(false);
}
}
```

I am not sure whether I can get the duration using the above way since I couldn't find any such property. Is their any other way of doing it? I don want to use QMediaPlayer. Any other alternate solution which can help me update my above code with Duration???

Answer (score 1):

**Using Qt**

You can try exploring the Qt's [Phonon Module](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/phonon-overview.html).

I think [this function](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/phonon-mediaobject.html#totalTime) in the Phonon's MediaObject class might be helpful in getting what you are trying to achieve.

P.S. Do read the warning written at the end of that function, to avoid getting wrong results.

---

Edit 1: 
**Without using Qt**

Read about TagLib Library [here](http://taglib.github.com/). Check [this](http://taglib.github.com/api/classTagLib_1_1AudioProperties.html#acdd3ffe79f3a76ec5edb85bb911407e1) function they have mentioned regarding getting the length of file. And it is under LGPL as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It says: `Get the total time (in milliseconds) of the file currently being played.` But I dont want to play it. I just want to iterate the drives, search for the files and display the duration in TreeView like how I am displaying other properties in my given code above.

Comment: Wow this is GOOD :) So using TagLib I can use its member function like length and get the duration of file in my above given Qt Code???

Comment: @OwaisNabiWani TagLib is used pretty much in extracting the meta data of files, supporting several audio formats. I havent used it personally ,but heard that it is very easy to use. How about trying it and letting us all know if it is any good :-)

Comment: Yeah brother, I will try and see if I can get it done. Will drop you a comment :)